# Android - Properly creating and countdown of timer?

Tags: android, timer

Ive been working hard this week at learning android, and one thing I cant find a good 
example for is timers, so if someone could maybe take the time to write asimple timer that counts down and displays in a textview, i would be eternally grateful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will start from 30sec and end when it reaches 1 sec. Please note that timer uses milliseconds instead for seconds.

1 sec = 1000 milliseconds

Thus, 30 sec = 30x1000 milliseconds

`mTextField` is your regular TextView, replace it with your own TextView.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: what do I do if I want something to occur when the timer reaches 0?

Comment: Then add that in `onFinish()`.